# AJAX Call with Elasticsearch Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, couchdb, elasticsearch

I've been trying to figure out how to correctly request data from elasticsearch using a jQuery AJAX call.  I either get an parsing error or I'll get every document in the index I'm searching under.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var timer = null;
    function dicom_search() {
        var box = $('#s_box').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:9200/dicoms/dicoms/_search',
            type: 'POST',
            //contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                query:{match:{_all:$('#s_box').val()}},
                pretty: true,
                fields: '_id'
            },
            success: function(response) {
                var data = response.hits.hits;
                var doc_ids = [];
                var source = null;
                var content = '';

                if (data.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        source = data[i].fields;
                        doc_ids.push(source._id);
                        content = content + ' ' + source._id + '<br />';
                    }

                    $('#res').removeClass('text-error').addClass('text-success').html(content);
                } else {
                    $('#res').removeClass('text-success').addClass('text-error').html('No results found.');
                }


            }
        });
    }

    $('#s_box').live('keyup', function() {

        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = setTimeout(dicom_search, 600);

    });
});
```

Here is my error:

```
{
   "error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], total failure; shardFailures {[GUiivW0TQVSNv2HQyxu8Vw][dicoms][0]: SearchParseException[[dicoms][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [_na_]]]; nested: ElasticSearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent from org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.ChannelBufferBytesReference@779479bb]; }{[GUiivW0TQVSNv2HQyxu8Vw][dicoms][3]: SearchParseException[[dicoms][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [_na_]]]; nested: ElasticSearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent from org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.ChannelBufferBytesReference@779479bb]; }{[GUiivW0TQVSNv2HQyxu8Vw][dicoms][1]: SearchParseException[[dicoms][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [_na_]]]; nested: ElasticSearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent from org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.ChannelBufferBytesReference@779479bb]; }{[GUiivW0TQVSNv2HQyxu8Vw][dicoms][4]: SearchParseException[[dicoms][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [_na_]]]; nested: ElasticSearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent from org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.ChannelBufferBytesReference@779479bb]; }{[GUiivW0TQVSNv2HQyxu8Vw][dicoms][2]: SearchParseException[[dicoms][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [_na_]]]; nested: ElasticSearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent from org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.ChannelBufferBytesReference@779479bb]; }]",
   "status":500
}
```

EDIT: I figured it out:

```
var data = {
            query: {
                match: {
                    _all: $('#s_box').val()
                }
            },
            fields: '_id'
        }; 

$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:9200/dicoms/dicoms/_search',
            type: 'POST',
            //contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function(response) {
                var data = response.hits.hits;
                var doc_ids = [];
                var source = null;
                var content = '';

                if (data.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        source = data[i].fields;
                        doc_ids.push(source._id);
                        content = content + ' ' + source._id + '<br />';
                    }

                    $('#res').removeClass('text-error').addClass('text-success').html(content);
                } else {
                    $('#res').removeClass('text-success').addClass('text-error').html('No results found.');
                }


            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var jso = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                error_note('section', 'error', '(' + jqXHR.status + ') ' + errorThrown + ' --<br />' + jso.error);
            }
        });
```

Comment: The key difference between your original code and your edited code is that you converted your javascript object to JSON and passed that into the $.ajax()'s "data" property by doing JSON.stringify(data).  I believe that was the key to getting this to work.

Comment: could you post your entire html page somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look here: https://github.com/dadoonet/devoxxfr_demo/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L512

It could help you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your AJAX call, I'd suggest you use this tool called **Postman**. Postman has a simple motto -

> Making API development easy

So in case you have trouble writing your ES requests, or maybe you decide not to use jQuery AJAX/XHR, and maybe you'd like to use cURL/Unirest/NSURL and what not, you can just use the Postman request builder to write down your simple Http Request, then you'll find a link called *code* in the box right below that, and you can generate requests in the language of your choice using that. Including AJAX, yes. So I'd recommend you try using that.

Here's the link where you can download Postman from - https://www.getpostman.com/postman